# I'm getting 'undefined' when trying to fetch data from my own API

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, google-chrome-extension

Please excuse me if I'm not using the correct terminology with my question, I'm still very much a beginner with web development.

I am building a chrome extension that is pulling a value from the current tab, then querying my PostgreSQL database through a web API that I built separately. When I use **fetch** with my API, I am getting confirmation that I have successfully connected to the API but the result I am getting back is ***undefined***. I'm hoping someone can help me?

I have a feeling it might be something to do with ***Access-Control-Allow-Origin*** but I really need some guidance on this.

Thanks in advance!

**API:**

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "postgres_api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^8.5.1"
  }
}
```

*index.js*

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const pool = require("./db");

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "chrome-extension://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(express.json()); // => req.body

app.get("/bamboo/:product", async (req, res) => {
  const { product } = req.params;
  console.log(product);

  try {
    const getProducts = await pool.query(
      `SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name like '%${product}%'`
    );
    const final_data = res.json(getProducts.rows);
    console.log(final_data);
    return final_data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

***Chrome extension:***

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Bamboo",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "/images/icon.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "/images/icon.png"
  }
}
```

*script.js*

```
function isEmptyOrSpaces(str) {
  return str == null || str.trim() === "";
}

// let tab_title = "";
function display_search(results) {
  const search = results[0];

  if (isEmptyOrSpaces(search)) {
    document.querySelector(".search-results").textContent =
      "No input detected...";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".search-results").textContent =
      "We found 7 items similar to '" + search + "'...";

    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/bamboo/${search}`)
      .then(() =>
        console.log(
          `API connected successfully: http://localhost:8080/bamboo/${search}`
        )
      )
      .then((res) => console.log(res)) // ******** this is where i'm getting undefined ********
      .catch((err) => console.error("Something went wrong:", err));
  }
}

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
  let tab = tabs[0];
  // tab_title = tab.title;
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id, // id of the tab in which to run the script
    {
      code: 'document.querySelector("#twotabsearchtextbox").value',
    },
    display_search
  );
});
```

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: @chris i am getting the result to the API, but I just can't grab that result on the chrome extension end

Comment: To make a network request the URL should be added to `permissions`, see [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr). Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.